# play slick updating enumeration column

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, play-slick

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update a column with type enumeration using play-slick.

Here's my enum and case class:

```
object TestStatus extends Enumeration {
  type TestStatus = Value
  val Status1 = Value("Status1")
}
case class Test (
  id: String,
  status: TestStatus
)
```

and the table mapping:

```
class Tests(tag: Tag) extends Table[Test](tag, "tests") {
  implicit val statusColumn = MappedColumnType.base[TestStatus, String](_.toString, TestStatus.withName)
  override def * = (id, status) <> ((Test.apply _).tupled, Test.unapply)
  val id = column[String]("id", 0.PrimaryKey)
  val status = column[TestStatus]("status")
}
```

when I try to go and update a Tests row, I get an error:

```
object TestQueries extends TableQuery[Tests](new Tests(_)) {
  def updateStatus(id: String, newStatus: TestStatus) = {
    TestQueries.filter(_.id === id).map(_.status).update(newStatus)
  }
}

[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection,
[error]  you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List),
[error]  or you forgot to import a driver api into scope.
[error]   Required level: slick.lifted.FlatShapeLevel
[error]      Source type: slick.lifted.Rep[models.TestStatus.Value]
[error]    Unpacked type: T
[error]      Packed type: G
[error]     TestQueries.filter(_.id === id).map(_.status).update(newStatus)
[error]                                        ^
```

IntelliJ is showing that `TestQueries.filter(_.id === id).map(_.status)` has type `Query[Nothing, Nothing, Seq]`, which makes me think the problem is with the specific column rather than with the update function.

Updating the id works fine using the same structure.

Comment: It seems like only `Tests` class has implicit column mapping for `TestStatus`. Could you clarify whether `TestQueries` have proper column mapping in scope too? Just for sake of experiment try to duplicate `statusColumn` value inside of `TestQueries` and check if it compiles.

Comment: @AdamBat It is a bit unclear from my code, but I tried copying the column mapping to various scopes: `TestStatus` object level as well as `TestQueries` level, all with the same results.

Comment: Could you provide repository with replicated issue? I copied your code ad hoc and got same compiler error. Duplicating `TestStatus` column mapping in `TestQueries`, like I suggested, in the comment above, helped to resolve the problem. Here is my gist showing what I've done exactly: https://gist.github.com/Dasiu/ae4fa9bfa9077569e5e07a02aa1493f0

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the custom column type of `TestStatus.Value`. This is how slick allows you to build a custom column type by mapping it to an already supported type:

```scala
implicit def testStatCT: BaseTypedType[TestStatus.Value] = 
  MappedColumnType.base[TestStatus.Value, String](
    enum => enum.toString, str => TestStatus.withName(str)
  )
```

this implicit needs to be imported wherever implicit resolutions such as the one in your example fail (or better yet defined in the `TestStatus` object so that it's always available) this way slick can have evidence that `TestStatus.Value` is a `BaseTypedType` which basically just means that something is a supported column type.

For further read on column mapping you can look at [Slick Documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/userdefined.html#using-custom-scalar-types-in-queries)